Give an example of when $X$ can be in $S$
First post ever.
The original question: Let $S=\{X: X\text{ is a set},\space X\text{ not in }X\}$. Give an example of when $X$ is in $S$?
Proof:
I know that $X$ and $S$ are sets.
Suppose that all the elements of $X$ are in $S$ and that $S$ has more elements than $X$. (I'm thinking that $X$ is a subset of $S$).
If all the elements of $X$ are in $S$, but not all the elements of $S$ are in $X$, then $X$ is a subset of $S$.
My thoughts: Since $X$ is a subset of $S$, elements of $X$ are in $S$. But is that the same as $X \in S$? Ex: $S=\{1,2,3,4\}$ and $X=\{1,2\}$. Can I substitute $X$ for elements of $S$? $S=\{X,3,4\}$?

Doesn't Russell's paradox say $S$ is not a set?

By Russell's paradox, $S$ is not a set but a proper class.
A set $X$ being a subclass of $S$ does not imply it being an element of $S$, and the answer to the questions in your example is a loud "three times no!": $\{\{1,2\},3,4\}\ne\{1,2,3,4\}$ (taking for granted that $1,2,3,4$ are distinct), since the first of these two sets has only three elements.
As for your main question: $X=\varnothing$ does the job.
Incidentally, note that with the axiom of regularity, $S$ is the whole "universe", i.e.  every set $X$ (be it a subclass of $S$ or not) is an element of $S$.
